# Linking to a Specific Library with C

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have to use the [SNAP](http://snap-graph.sourceforge.net/) C-library.

I compiled my file snap_test.c with the following command:

```
gcc -fopenmp -c -I/home/myName/SNAPDIR/include snap_test.c
```

And then linked it with the library:

```
gcc -fopenmp -o snap_test -L/home/myName/SNAPDIR/lib -lsnap snap_test.o
```

But running the program leads to an error:

```
./snap_test: error while loading shared libraries: libsnap.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In the lib-dir there are those dirs and files:

```
libsnap.a  
libsnap.la  
libsnap.so        (dir)
libsnap.so.0      (dir)
libsnap.so.0.0.0
```

I guess the problem is the different versions of the libraries?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `/home/myName/SNAPDIR/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH+=:/home/myName/SNAPDIR/lib
```